# Decrease the data size a webview uses while loading a website say www.example.com.

Tags: android, android-webview

Here is the code I've used for WebView in my App.

```
WebView web = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webview);
    web.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
    @Override
    public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl){

    }
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url){
        view.loadUrl(url);
        return true;

    }
    });
    Toast.makeText(this,"Loading...", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    web.loadUrl("http://example.com");
```

I want a webview which will save max data usage. Currently my App is eating 2.5MB for loading my webpage. Any idea to make my App eat minimal data?

Comment: On the client side, I don't think there's a lot you can do, other than disable images, etc.

Comment: Yeah I agree with you, but how come Opera Mini and UC browser can do so?

Comment: They have servers through which all data passes before being sent to the browsers. These servers compress the page content before delivering to the browser.